# Help Proving $\int_{0}^xf(x-t)g(t) dt=x, $ for all $x\geq 0$.

Tags: real-analysis

> Question: Let $f,g:[0,\infty)\to \mathbb R$ be continuous functions that equal $1$ identically on $[0,1],$ are differentiable in $(1,\infty) $ and satisfy $$ xf'(x)=-f(x-1), xg'(x)=g(x-1), \forall x>1.$$ Prove that $\int_{0}^xf(x-t)g(t) dt=x, $ for all $x\geq 0$.

Since $f,g$ are differentiable on $(1,\infty)$, so constructing an ODE after differentiating the given expression wasn't a good idea. So I started  considering $I(x)=\int_{0}^xf(x-t)g(t)dt$. Using Leibnitz, $I'(x)=\int_{0}^x\frac{\delta}{\delta x}(f(x-t))g(t)dt\ + f(0)g(x)=\int_{0}^xf'(x-t)g(t) dt\ + g(x)$. Stuck here!

Tried using the Mean Value Theorem for $f'(x)$ on $x>1$ so that I can simplify the integral, could't get anything from there.
Finally tried using integration By-Parts, same situation.

Any hint appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
f,g:[ 0,\infty )\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are continuous functions such that: 
$f(x)=g(x)=1$ for x $\in$ [ 0,1]
$f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are differentiable in (1,$\infty$) and satisfy:
$(1)$ $xf'(x)=-f(x-1)$ $\forall  x>1 $
$(2)$ $xg'(x)=g( x-1)$ $\forall  x>1 $

For $0<x<1$,consider,
$h(x) =\int _{0}^{x} f(x-t)g(t)dt$
$0<t<1 \Longrightarrow g(t)=1$
$0<t<x<1 \Longrightarrow 0>-t>-x >-1 \Longrightarrow 1>x>(x-t)>0>(x-1) \Longrightarrow f(x-t) =1\Longrightarrow$
$h(x)=\int _{0}^{x} 1dt=x$

For $1<x<2$, consider,:
From $(1), 1<x<2, xf'(x)=-f(x-1)$
$1<x<2 \Longrightarrow 0<x-1<1 \Longrightarrow f(x-1) =1 \Longrightarrow$
$1<x<2 \Longrightarrow xf'(x)=-1 \Longrightarrow f'(t)=-\frac{1}{t} \Longrightarrow \int_{1}^{x} f'(t)dt\ =-\int_{1}^{x}\frac{1}{t} dt \Longrightarrow f(x)-f( 1)=-(\ln(x)) \Longrightarrow f(x) =1-\ln( x)$
Similarly, for $1<x<2, g'(t) =\frac{1}{t} \Longrightarrow \int _{1}^{x} g'(t)dt =\int _{1}^{x}\frac{1}{t}dt \Longrightarrow g(x)-g(1)=(\ln(x)) \Longrightarrow g(x) =1+\ln( x)$

So, now, we have:
$h(x)=\int _{0}^{x}f(x-t) g(t)dt=\int_{0}^{1}f(x-t)g(t)dt+\int _{1}^{x}f(x-t)g(t)dt=\int_{0}^{1}f(x-t)dt\ +\ \int_{1}^{x}f(x-t)g(t) dt$
If we want $0<x-t<1 \Longrightarrow -1<t-x<0 \Longrightarrow x-1<t<x$,so we further break up the above integral as:
$h(x)=\int_{0}^{x-1}f(x-t)dt\ +\int_{x-1}^{1}f(x-t)dt+\int _{1}^{x}f(x-t)g(t)dt$
In second and third integral, we have $f(x-t) =1$
In first integral, $0<t<x-1 \Longrightarrow 0>-t>1-x \Longrightarrow x>x-t>1 \Longrightarrow f(x-t)=1-\ln(x-t)$
In the third integral, $t>1 \Longrightarrow g(t)=1+\ln(t)$
Combining, these, we get:
$h(x)=\int _{0}^{x-1}[1-\ln(x-t)]dt +\int_{x-1}^{1}1dt+\int_{1}^{x} 1.(1+\ln(t))dt \Longrightarrow$
$h(x)=(x-1)-\int_{x}^{1}\ln(u)(-du)+(1-(x-1))+(x-1)+t\ln( t)\Bigl|_{1}^{x}\Longrightarrow$
$h(x)=(x-1)-\int_{1}^{x}\ln(u)(du)+1-(x-1)+(x-1)+x\ln(x) \Longrightarrow$
$h(x)=-u\ln(u)\Bigl|_{1}^{x}+1+x-1+x\ln( x)\Longrightarrow$
$h(x)=-x\ln(x)+x+x\ln(x) \Longrightarrow h(x) =x$


Now, assume that, $h(x)=\int_{0}^{x}f(x-t)g(t)dt=x,$ for $x<n$
We show that $h(x)=x$ for $n<x<n+1$ as well:
$h(x)=\int_{0}^{x}f(x-t)g(t)dt$
For $x-1<t<x \Longrightarrow -x<-t<-(x-1) \Longrightarrow 0<x-t<1 \Longrightarrow f(x-t)=1$ for
$x-1<t<x \Longrightarrow$
$h(x)=\int_{0}^{x-1}f(x-t)g(t)dt+\int_{x-1}^{x}f(x-t)g(t)dt=\int _{0}^{x-1}f(x-t)g(t)dt+\int_{x-1}^{x}g(t)dt \Longrightarrow $
$h(x)=\int_{x-1}^{x}g(t)dt+\int_{0}^{x-1}\underbrace{f(x-t)g(t)}_{u} .\underbrace{1}_{v} dt\Longrightarrow$
$h(x)=\int_{x-1}^{x}g(t)dt+\left(f(x-t)g(t)\int_{0}^{x-1}1dt\right) -\left[\int_{0}^{x-1}-f'(x-t)g(t)tdt+\int_{0}^{x-1}f(x-t)g'(t) tdt\right]$
$h(x)=\int_{x-1}^{x}g(t)dt+f(x-t)g(t)t\Bigl|_{0}^{x-1}+\int_{0}^{x-1} f'(x-t)g(t)tdt-\int_{0}^{x-1}f(x-t)(g'(t)t)dt$
$h(x)=\underbrace{\int_{x-1}^{x}g(t)dt}_{1}+g(x-1)(x-1) +\underbrace{\int_{0}^{x-1}f'(x-t)g(t)tdt}_{2} -\underbrace{\int _{0}^{x-1}f(x-t)(g'(t)t)dt}_{3}$
For integral 3, for $t \in [0,1], g'(t) =0$, for t $\in (1,x-1)$ , $g'(t)t=g( t-1) \Longrightarrow$
$\int_{1}^{x-1}f(x-t)g(t-1)dt=\int_{1}^{x-1} f((x-1)-( t-1))g(t-1) dt$
Now, $n<x<n+1 \Longrightarrow n-1<x-1<n$, so by induction assumption, we have integral 3 as:
$\int_{1}^{u}f(u-(t-1))g(t-1)d(t-1)\Longrightarrow$
Let $(t-1)=v$, so we have : integral (3)$=\int_{0}^{u-1}f(u-v)g(v)dv$
By induction assumption, since $u=x-1<n$, we have, $\int_{0}^{u}f(u-v)g(v)dv=u\Longrightarrow$
$\int_{u-1}^{u}g(v)dv+\int_{0}^{u-1}f(u-v)g(v)dv=u\Longrightarrow \int_{0}^{u-1}f(u-v)g(v)dv=u-\int_{u-1}^{u}g(v)dv=(x-1)-\int_{x-2}^{x-1}g(v)dv$

Now, consider integral (2), we get the following:
$\int_{0}^{x-1}f'(x-t)g(t)tdt=-\int_{0}^{x-1}f'(x-t)g(t)(x-t) dt+x\int_{0}^{x-1}f'(x-t)g(t)dt\Longrightarrow$
Now, as before: for $t \in [0,x-1], 1<x-t<x \Longrightarrow (x-t) f'( x-t)=-f(x-t-1) \Longrightarrow$
$\int_{0}^{x-1}f'(x-t)g(t)tdt=\int_{0}^{x-1}f(x-t-1)g(t)dt+x\int _{0}^{x-1}f'(x-t)g(t)dt\Longrightarrow$
$\int_{0}^{x-1}f'(x-t)g(t)tdt=\int_{0}^{x-1}f((x-1)-t)g(t)dt+x\int _{0}^{x-1}f'(x-t)g(t)dt=(x-1)+x\int_{0}^{x-1}f'(x-t)g(t) dt\Longrightarrow$
$h(x)=\underbrace{\int_{x-1}^{x}g(t)dt}_{1}+g(x-1)(x-1)+(x-1)+x\int _{0}^{x-1}f'(x-t)g(t)dt-\left[(x-1)-\int_{x-2}^{x-1}g(v)dv\right] \Longrightarrow$
$h(x)=\int_{x-1}^{x}g(t)dt+\int_{x-2}^{x-1}g(v)dv+g(x-1)(x-1)+x\int _{0}^{x-1}f'(x-t)g(t)dt$
In this entire equation, let $(x-1)=u\Longrightarrow$
$h(x)=\int_{u-1}^{u+1}g(t)dt+g(u)(u)+(u+1)\int_{0}^{u}f'(u+1-t)g(t) dt$
In this $u<n$, so going back to induction, assumption, we have:
For $x<n, h(x)=\int_{0}^{x}f(x-t)g(x)dt=x$
Differentiating both sides w.r.t $x$, we get:
$f(x-x)g(x) +\int_{0}^{x}f'(x-t)g(t)dt=1\Longrightarrow$
$\int_{0}^{x}f'(x-t)g(t)dt=1-g(x) \Longrightarrow$
Note that for, $x-1<t<x,f(x-t)=1 \Longrightarrow f'(x-t) =0\Longrightarrow$
$\int_{0}^{x-1}f'(x-t)g(t)dt+\int_{x-1}^{x}f'(x-t)g(t)dt=1-g(x) \Longrightarrow \int_{0}^{x-1} f'(x-t)g(t)dt=1-g(x) \Longrightarrow $
Let,$x-1=u \Longrightarrow$
$\int_{0}^{u}f'(u+1-t)g(t)dt=1-g(u+1)\Longrightarrow$
$h(x)=\int_{u-1}^{u+1}g(t)dt+g(u)(u)+(u+1)[1-g(u+1)]$
$h(x)=\int_{u-1}^{u+1}g(t)dt+g(u)(u)+(u+1)-(u+1)g(u+1)$
$h(x)=(u+1) +\underbrace{\int_{u-1}^{u+1}g(t)dt}_{1}+g(u)(u)-(u+1)g( u+1)$
In this, consider integral 1 as below:
$\int_{u-1}^{u+1}g(t)dt=\int_{u}^{u+1}g(t)dt+\int_{u-1}^{u}g(t) dt=tg(t)\Bigl|_{u}^{u+1}-\int_{u}^{u+1}g'(t)tdt+\int_{u-1}^{u}g(t) dt\Longrightarrow$
$\int_{u-1}^{u+1}g(t)dt=(u+1)g(u+1)-ug(u)-\int_{u}^{u+1}g(t-1) dt+\int_{u-1}^{u}g(t)dt\Longrightarrow$
$\int_{u-1}^{u+1}g(t)dt=(u+1)g(u+1)-ug(u)-\int_{u-1}^{u}g(z)dz+\int _{u-1}^{u}g(t)dt$
Putting the value of integral 1 back in h(x) , we get:
$h(x)=(u+1)+(u+1)g(u+1)-ug(u)+g(u)(u)-(u+1)g(u+1)$
Hence,$h(x)=(u+1)=x-1+1=x$
Hence,for $n<x<n+1,h(x)=x$
So, by induction, we have the required result of $h(x)=x$ for all x in $\mathbb{R}$